# Block Remains same height but text gets ellipsis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for the vague title.

I'm trying to have a row of blocks, each block contains an image, a H2 title, a description and a link a the bottom.

Each block should remain the same height, but obviously the titles can vary in lines which means the description has to ellipsis at a smaller height.

What's happening below is the link is not being accounted for, even though I have declared it.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dLp38687/15/)

Here is the code that's running this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".example").each(function() {

    var imgheight = 300;
    var linkheight = $(this).find(".affiliate-tag").height();
    var h2height = $(this).find(".desc h2").height();

    $(this).find(".desc").height(670 - imgheight - h2height - linkheight - 30);

    $(this).find(".desc").dotdotdot({
      after: "a.readmore"
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.example {
  background: #eee;
  height: 670px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 40px;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.desc {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 30px;
}
.affiliate-tag {
  padding: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.dotdotdot/1.6.10/jquery.dotdotdot.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="example">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/9ac8f53d4b3ec8d77865fd1b542a7b1f_xRgXa9UV_l.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
      <h2>This is a title of a post and it can span 2 lines and maybe three?</h2>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="example">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/3156205047987_i80wZOig_l.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
      <h2>This is a title of a post and it can span 2 lines</h2>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

    </div>
    <a href="www.google.com" class="affiliate-tag">Go to google.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

** UPDATE **

Here is similar to the effect I'm trying to achieve. http://dunked.com/showcase

But what I'm trying to do is have a link underneath the description, and for the description to take the links height into account. Then reduce the descriptions height so that it ellipsis at a smaller size.

Comment: try this: http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/  or just try goggling "ellipsis js"...

Comment: I'm already using this. As you can see in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue why the text seems to appear to end at different heights is because of the different line heights of the `h2` and `p` elements. If you take into account the design principle of a **constant vertical rhythm** (you can read more about it [here](https://drewish.com/tools/vertical-rhythm/), [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/), [here](http://typecast.com/blog/4-simple-steps-to-vertical-rhythm) and [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/improving-layout-with-vertical-rhythm--webdesign-14070)), this can be easily rectified:

```
.desc h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.desc p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

This will make the bottom of the text to end at the same vertical height, because the line-height of each `p` row is a multiplier of the `h2` element line-height.

Also, to include paddings in your calculations, you should use `outerHeight()` instead of just `height()`. There are some calculations that has to be fixed, but it seems to be working now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".example").each(function () {

        var imgheight = 300;
        var linkheight = $(this).find(".affiliate-tag").outerHeight();
        var h2height = $(this).find(".desc h2").outerHeight();

        $(this).find(".desc").height(670 - imgheight - h2height - linkheight);

        console.log();

        $(this).find(".desc").dotdotdot({
            after: "a.readmore"
        });
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/dLp38687/18/

Comment: Thanks Terry, but as you can see the link is getting pushed off the bottom. What should be happening is the description should be ending sooner to accommodate for the <a> tag's height.

Comment: @Jonathan Can you include a screenshot in your question to indicate the exact visual outcome you want? It is difficult to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @Jonathan I think I know what you mean now: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/dLp38687/18/

Comment: Yep, you got it. Hard concept to get across in a question. Thanks for this! +1

Comment: Hi Terry, not too sure if your experienced in rails. But this is throwing up another error on my clients site. Explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754184/same-height-boxes-with-ellipsis-text Hope you can help!

Comment: Would love for you to take a look at it if you don't have exp in Rails anyway :) @terry

Answer (score 0):

adding `box-sizing: border-box;` makes easier to work with paddings. That and ajusting `.affiliate-tag` does the trick for me

add
`* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}`
 and change
`.affiliate-tag{
    padding-left:30px;
        display:block;
}`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aud2mhs3/1/)